# Modifying an .xlsx file (Excel 2007 and newer)

Tags: perl, excel, xlsx

I successfully parsed an `xls` file using `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser` and modified it with `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`.

However working with `xlsx` file is a whole different thing.
I am trying to figure out how to work with `Spreadsheet::XLSX` for parsing and how to make it work with `Excel::Writer::XLSX`.  `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser` has a `SaveAs()` method that makes it possible to apply `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` methods on the parsed `xml` file, but I don't understand how to make it work with xlsx file

edit:
when using `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser` and `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` I can write:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

# Open the template with SaveParser
my $parser   = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
my $template = $parser->Parse('template.xls');

# Rewrite the file or save as a new file
$workbook = $template->SaveAs('new.xls');

# Use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel methods
my $worksheet  = $workbook->sheets(0);
$worksheet->write($row+2, $col, "World2");

$workbook->close();
```

I would like to do the same with `xlsx` files. therefore I'm trying to use `Spreadsheet::XLSX` and `Excel::Writer::XLSX`.
Instead of

```
my $parser   = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
my $template = $parser->Parse('template.xls');
```

I use

```
my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('test.xlsx');
```

Now, after parsing the `xlsx` file I would like to add some data to it and I don't know how to do it.
As you can see above when using `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser` I used `SaveAs()` function,
but `Spreadsheet::XLSX` dosn't have a `SaveAs()` method. So how do I add data to parsed `xlsx` file?

I could not find an answer to my question in this [link](http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX).

Thanks you for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean: "how to make it work"? There is an example program here: http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm What exactly doesn't work? We like concrete questions here with code samples.

Comment: I've edited and added code example. I hope that my question is clearer now and somebody can help... Thanks :)

Comment: Please note that `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` is in "maintenance-only mode" as per the [description section on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#DESCRIPTION), replacement is [`Excel:Writer::XLSX`](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.96/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm).

Answer (score 2):

The Spreadsheet::XLSX module is a *Parser*, i.e. it is not supposed to write files, only to read and understand them.

To write the file back to disk, I suggest you the Excellent (no pun intended :) )  **Excel::Writer::XLSX** by John McNamara.

http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm

Basically you can slurp (via Spreadsheet::XLSX) the XLSX file into a multilevel hash reference structured like this:

```
$xlsx_as_read->{worksheet_name}->{column}->{row}=value;
```

Modifying the example on the CPAN link you posted:

```
use Text::Iconv;
my $converter = Text::Iconv -> new ("utf-8", "windows-1251");

# Text::Iconv is not really required.
# This can be any object with the convert method. Or nothing.

use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
my $xlsx_as_read;

my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('test.xlsx', $converter);

foreach my $sheet (@{$excel -> {Worksheet}}) {

       printf("Sheet: %s\n", $sheet->{Name});
       $sheet -> {MaxRow} ||= $sheet -> {MinRow};

        foreach my $row ($sheet -> {MinRow} .. $sheet -> {MaxRow}) {

               $sheet -> {MaxCol} ||= $sheet -> {MinCol};
               foreach my $col ($sheet -> {MinCol} ..  $sheet -> {MaxCol}) {
                       my $cell = $sheet -> {Cells} [$row] [$col];
                       if ($cell) {
                           $xlsx_as_read->{$sheet->{Name}}->{$col}->{$row}=$cell -> {Val};
                       }
               } 
       }
}
```

and then pour it back to an Excel::Writer::XLSX workbook, which can be written to disk.

```
my $new_workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'output_file_name.xlsx' );
#populate cells with a loop similar to the one before, 
#iterating on $xlsx_as_read
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('test.xlsx', $converter);

Answer (score 0):

```
my $excel_xlsx = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('input_x.xlsx');
my ($sheet_xlsx, $row, $col, $cell);
```

## Please write the content in the xls file immediately:

```
my $excel_xls = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('input.xls');
my $sheet_xls = $excel_xls->add_worksheet();
```

## Fetch the content:

```
for $sheet_xlsx ( @{ $excel_xlsx->{Worksheet} } )
{
    for $row ( $sheet_xlsx->{MinRow} .. $sheet_xlsx->{MaxRow} )
    {
        for $col ( $sheet_xlsx->{MinCol} .. $sheet_xlsx->{MaxCol} )
        {
            my $cell = $sheet_xlsx->{Cells}[$row][$col];
            if($cell->{Val})
            {
            }
```

## Write here in the xls:

```
            $sheet_xls->write($row, $col, $cell->{Val});
        }
    }
}
```